# Implementing Kerberos authentication with Javamail

Tags: imap, jakarta-mail, kerberos

There is an [older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282279/javamail-imap-and-kerberos) that seems to be the only relevant discussion I have been able to find.

I am trying to implement Kerberos with Javamail (over IMAP) and I have gotten my self thoroughly confused on exactly what is to be done with mail.imap.sasl.mechanisms. Assume I give the value "GSS-API" but am kind of lost where to go from there. I notice that Javamail has an class IMAPSaslAuthernticator. It seems to me that this is what is needed but I can find precious little documentation on where or how to use it.

Any ideas?

NOTE: I wanted to post more code for my question, but according the site directions, full posts are only for answers. So, I have edited the code I originally posted question.

Below is the real meat. For now, once I pass this point I get the Message[] from the server and print the size to console.

SSL/TLS security is required so it is enabled below. In this example certificates are managed by a trusted keystore in Java.

```
private Folder folder;
private Session session;
private Store store;

public boolean connectToKerberosMail() {
    if (folder != null && folder.isOpen()) {
        return true;
    }

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

    properties.put("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout",600000);
    properties.put("mail.imaps.timeout",601000);
    properties.put("mail.imaps.fetchsize", 65000);
    properties.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.imaps.starttls.required", "false");

    properties.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable","true");
    properties.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms","GSSAPI");
    properties.put("mail.imaps.sasl.authorizationid",<user>);
    properties.put("mail.imaps.sasl.realm",<realm>);

    System.setProperty( "sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
    System.setProperty( "java.security.krb5.realm",<realm>);
    System.setProperty( "java.security.krb5.kdc", <ip-address>);  
    System.setProperty( "java.security.auth.login.config", "jaas.conf");
    System.setProperty( "javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

    try {
        session = Session.getInstance(properties);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session = null;
        return false;
    }

    session.setDebug(true);

    URLName url = new URLName("imaps", <host>, <port>, "", <user>, <pass>);
    store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, url);

    try {
        store.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        store = null;
        session = null;
        return false;           
    }

    return openFolder();
}
```

My jaas.conf file is as follows (the ticket cache was acquired from kinit):

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  principal="<principal>" 
  ticketCache="<cache-path>" 
  doNotPrompt="true" 
  useTicketCache="true" 
  debug="true";
};

com.sun.security.jgss.accept {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
  principal="<principal>" 
  ticketCache="<cache-path>" 
  doNotPrompt="true" 
  useTicketCache="true" 
  debug="true"; 
};
```

I recently posted here the output but noticed that some of my properties where designated "imap" instead of "imaps". So I am doing more testing before posintg output incase it changes.

In the mean time is what I have above correct? From what I understand I have to enable imap for the imap connection, startTLS for the TLS/SSL, and sasl for kerberos. But maybe something is overriding the another?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I say this in every response.  I don't know how to get the word out....

You almost certainly want to change `Session.getDefaultInstance()` to `Session.getInstance()`, although that's probably not the source of your problems.

Anyway, what does the protocol trace show when you run your program?  (`emailSession.setDebug(true);`)

I don't know enough about Kerberos, and especially how Kerberos works as a SASL mechanism, but aren't you going to have to specify some sort of password?  Or can it get the appropriate Kerberos ticket without asking you to prove who you are?

Comment: The documentation states Kerberos can be used by choosing the GSSAPI mechanism and the sasl properties above are in the IMAP api requiring things like Kerberos requires such as the realm.

I am successful in running a javamail client that connects directly to a mail server (IMAP) using explicit username and password. I also succeeded in connecting redirectly to the Kerberos server to request a ticket with a [helpful blog](http://thejavamonkey.blogspot.com/2008/04/clientserver-hello-world-in-kerberos.html).

So all the peices seem to exist the but I can't figure out how to connect them.

Comment: Figured out solution to Javamail & Kerberos! I plan to post here for everyone who has been searching for a code example. But I have one last issue before my solution is complete. I have to work with Kerberos over SSL. So I use the IMAPSSLStore. However the URLName requires a username and password. When I provide it Javamail gets a ticket from Kerberos and uses it to contact IMAP sever.

The issue remains is that I require Single-sign on where the user never has to provide the user/pwd. But IMAPSSLStore requires them and throws an exception.

How do I emplement single sign-on with javamail?

Comment: You may need to provide a dummy username and password if they're not actually used in the authentication exchange with the server.

Comment: Thanks but it seems that they are. Even with my ticketCache enabled I only succeed with the real user and pwd. Here is the output (messing the comment space): 
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=<host>, user=<real_user>, password=<non-null>
A0 LOGIN <real_user> dummyPwd
A0 NO Login failed: authentication failure.

Comment: However, if I use a real user/pwd then LOGIN succeeds and It conitnues from the point above with this:
IMAP DEBUG: IMAPProtocol noop
A1 NOOP
A1 OK Completed
DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
A2 SELECT <real_user> ...etc. Also note that using dummy user or pwd or both did not make a difference.

Comment: If JavaMail is using the LOGIN command to authenticate then it seems that you haven't successfully enabled SASL Kerberos support.

Comment: Yes you need to validate with Kerberos (Krb) at least once. You use kinit.exe found in your Java. This allows you to create a local ticket cache by validating with a pwd. The ticket you get is the validation for Krb so from then on (until expires) you can turn to krb and validate without using a pwd. THIS works. I have the krb ticket and can turn to krb. The new problem (explained in the 2nd answer below) is that after validating with the krb ticket, krb sends me the ticket for the imap server. But somehow it is not caching and so authentication with the imap fails. Any ideas as to the cause?

Comment: With regards to the "password" is required issue, I was able to use a stupid store uri of: imaps://:@myhost.mydomain.com/INBOX and connect using GSSAPI.  The username and password are empty but present in the URI.  Without this it won't even connect.  Also, as someone pointed out somewhere else, the service principal requested for the connection is imaps, not imap as is typical.  Additionally, the service ticket requested is based on the name in the uri, not the reverse DNS of the host connected to as is normal for kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

While not 100% the way there yet i made some discoveries. LOGIN was happening with the protocol in the NamedURL was "imap". I changed it to "imaps".

However, it look like javamail takes the protocol and host uses them to contruct the principal. protocol/host@realm? so I was applying to principal imaps/host@REALM which didnt exist so failed on a non-matching pricipals error.

So, we added this new principal to the servers and got past this.

But authentication is still failing. In the kerberos log I was approved and sent a ticket for accessing the mail. But I do not see it in my ticket cache (using klist) only the first ticket for accessing kerberos (I got from using kinit).

Comment: This part about the service principal (imap vs imaps) is spot on.  However for the "host" part it's also non-standard: it doesn't use reverse DNS for the host but rather the host given in the URI. Also, I don't believe java saves the service ticket in the ticket cache, it only reads it.